# Old story about earthman travelling Martian canal by boat

Tags: story-identification

I’m looking for a classic era short story featuring an Earthman travelling the Martian canals by boat.

Earth has been destroyed, and the only survivors are crews of returning spacecraft stranded on Mars. The great majority seem to be male. Martians appear to be humanoid but there is little contact between the races.

The central character avoids the main centres and travels a circuit, working as a handyman for his keep. The events of the story revolve around his return to a Martian family he hasn’t seen in some time, and the growing daughter of the family who is attracted to him, although he leaves without acting on this.

The mother consoles her, saying that he will surely return again.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Nice question.  You should add details of when/where you read this story, if you remember.  You should check out the other [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) that might also help.

Comment: Sounds like something from *The Martian Chronicles*.

Answer (score 12):

From memory of reading and liking it many years ago, I suspect you're thinking of [Time to Rest](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?67734) by John Wyndham.

There is a description of the story [on the Solar System Heritage web site](https://www.solarsystemheritage.com/time-to-rest-by-john-wyndham.html), and the full story is [available on Archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/New_Worlds_005v02_1949#page/n83/mode/2up).

Comment: That’s the one, thanks

Comment: I used to dream of Zaylo aged 14.

Comment: I mean, when _I_ was 14.